Is there a way to autofit the comment window height with Python's xlsxwriter?
I just implemented a way to attach various metadata to cells in the excel files we produce in our data validation interface for our scientific data django app.  I'm basically migrating from our usage of google sheets.
The one thing that google sheets was better at was displaying comments.  Whatever the content of the comment, the comment hover window automatically fit the size of the comment.  I don't use excel much, so I was underwhelmed when I first viewed attached comments on cells.  All the comment windows are the same size and depending on the line breaks, there's not even any indication that anything is truncated.
Has anyone figured out a way to at least autofit the height?  I looked at the docs, but could not find one.  The ways to change the height are via height or y_scale options, but none of that takes into account the content.  It just takes arbitrary numeric values.
The reason autofit would be advantageous is that the comment content is programmatically generated and will change from file to file: sometimes very little text, sometimes very large text.
Other annoyances that would be nice to be able to address:

Is there a way to select the color for the triangle that appears in the cell?  I'd like to differentiate between errors and innocuous comments.
Is there a way to make the comment remain when you hover over the comment window itself and make the text selectable without having to click to show the comment first?

Without manually showing and adjusting comment window dimensions:

After adjusting comment windows:


There is an AutoSize option for the comments. It is a enable/disable setting and when set enabled the comment window is sized to fit the text. This option does not appear to be in the Xlsxwriter code that I can see, though @jmcnamara may confirm this. You could enable it with Xlwings for example after the workbook creation.

Really! I could not find that in any docs. What I'd found was that the cell's wrap had to be set (I.e. you couldn't have the comment box autosize without wrapping the content of the cell - but I'm not sure I fully understood what I was reading)

You can try it out, just select the comment cell in Excel and select Format Comment and then the alignment tab, The option to select autosize will be in that tab.

Hmmm... I don't see an alignment tab. After selecting Format > Format Comment..., I get a Format Shape panel with a single tab (with no name, just an icon that appears to represent "shape" attributes) with expandable sections labeled Size and Properties, neither of which contains an autosize feature. I tried searching for "alignment" in the help menu: no results. So I tried to check for office updates, but it says "Updates are temporarily unavailable."

Attempting a fresh office install. Hopefully, I'll get this feature...

While I am waiting on the installer to finish, I was looking into xlwings and trying to wrap my head around it. Does it need a running instance of excel to work or can it operate only on a worksheet object in python on a linux server?

Right click on the edge of the comment box and select "Format Comment" and you will get the box with all tabs (8 tabs), otherwise clicking inside the comment will only get the 'Font' tab. Xlwings modifies Excel files using the Excel application, so does need that installed and therefore also requires Windows or MACOS to run Excel.

That's (needing excel running) what I was inferring from the xlwings feature-set, so unfortunately, this won't work as a solution for our needs. We're generating files for download from the server. I guess the best we can do might be to tell users how to do it manually, but for all comments. I see you can make a macro to do it for all. Maybe I can figure out a way to add a macro to the download file. Ref: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-comment-boxes-resizing-themselves-andor/3fdf3e72-6ca5-4186-a656-b7b6fd8db781?page=2&messageId=8d41f1bd-0d2c-44f8-852a-a9baeb7e8054

Well, after the Excel update and right-clicking the comment edge, there is no option to "Format Comment" other than in the top menubar. There are format text and format object options, but both are grayed out. If I select format object from the system menu bar anfter clicking the comment edge, I get the same panel without an autosize option. Perhaps it's a windows-only feature.

I don't know of any other way to access this "Format Comment" panel. I have only Excel on Win 10 but wasn't aware of any restrictions on other releases. There is a screenshot of the panel I made before in this question . I'd assume the function would still work if enabled programmatically but options to do that seem also limited for your scenario.

Alright, apparently the comment autosize feature was dropped in 2016 and comments' future as-is is not clear. They are moving toward "shapes", which is why I get a format shape panel. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/unable-to-format-comment-object-in-excel/222a3212-0eb7-4305-bc59-e9126c7ed910

OK, bit of a shame, so you're basically down to making a manual determination, which given your environment was likely going to be the case anyway. @jmcnamara has given his answer now too.

I don't see any reason for any shame. You were very helpful and contributed toward me moving forward on this. I had already implemented a solution similar to the current answer, though aesthetically, I may implement a change or 2 based on the answer.


Has anyone figured out a way to at least autofit the height?

There isn't anything in the file format to autofit the height of a comment. You will need to make some estimate based on the string length and wrapping. An accurate calculation would need to take into account the font metrics.

Is there a way to select the color for the triangle that appears in the cell? I'd like to differentiate between errors and innocuous comments.

I don't believe so. That is a fixed property of Excel.

Is there a way to make the comment remain when you hover over the comment window itself and make the text selectable without having to click to show the comment first?

You can either set the visble property for each comment or use the worksheet show_comments() method.
The example below shows some of these options and workarounds:
import textwrap
import xlsxwriter

comment1 = """The unique name of the biological sample.

MUST match the sample names in the peak annotation
file, minus any appended suffixes.
"""

comment2 = """The date the sample was collected.

Format: YYYY-MM-DD.
"""


# Approximate esitmate of the number of lines in a wrapped comment.
def count_wrapped_lines(comment):
    num_lines = 0
    segments = comment.splitlines()
    for segment in segments:
        if segment == "":
            num_lines += 1
        else:
            lines = textwrap.wrap(segment, width=30)
            num_lines += len(lines)

    if num_lines == 0:
        num_lines = 1

    return num_lines


# Map the number of lines to a pixel height.
def comment_height_in_pixels(comment):
    num_lines = count_wrapped_lines(comment)
    return num_lines * 16


# Create a new workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("comments.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Write some comments.
worksheet.write("A1", "Sample")
worksheet.write_comment(
    "A1", comment1, {"height": comment_height_in_pixels(comment1), "y_offset": 150}
)

worksheet.write("B1", "Date")
worksheet.write_comment(
    "B1", comment2, {"height": comment_height_in_pixels(comment2), "y_offset": 50}
)


# Make all comments visible.
worksheet.show_comments()


workbook.close()


Output:

